# How can I devide 2 columns whith a vertical line with Wordpress - divi?

Tags: wordpress

On my site, there are two columns and I would like to separate them with a 1px line, right at the middle of the site.

I never used wordpress nor divi, but now I have to.

Answer (score 0):

really long answer so ill have to post the elegants themes link for you to run through [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-turn-horizontal-dividers-into-vertical-ones-with-divi)